# How to root a ZTE N817

Tags: rooting

I am looking for an easy, free, and safe way to root my ZTE N817 without ruining my phone are there any programs or apps that I can use

Answer (score 0):

PC version of iroot v 1.8.8. might help check out link below

https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/help/zte-n817-root-t3443935